# Which is the difference between LOAD DATA INPATH and LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

While using the Hive Console, which is the difference between using `LOCAL` those commands?:

- LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INPATH '/home/user/sample.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employee;
- LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/user/sample.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employee;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer:

- **'LOCAL'** signifies that the input file is on the local file system.
- If **'LOCAL'** is omitted then it looks for the file in HDFS.

Source: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-DMLOperations

Answer (score 2):

Local keyword load the file from local file system in this case file is **copied**

when you omit the local keyword it take file from HDFS location in this case file is **moved** to new location, means you will not find the file again in provided hdfs location